# Bootstrap Footer - Unable to move button using margins

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have countered an issue with the checkout button, I wasn't able to move it using margin-right and I am stuck here. It is stuck to the right side making it difficult to move it. I would want it to align vertically with the total coins.

```css
.coinsTotalRow {
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

#checkoutModalBtn {
  background-color: var(--pri-color);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 8rem 100rem auto auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

#checkoutButtonStyle {
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #111111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3rem 5.6rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="coinsTotalRow">
    <p class="checkoutTotal">Total Coins: </p>
    <p id="checkoutcoinsTotal" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 10)">

      <p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" href="#checkoutModal" id="checkoutButtonStyle" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
  <button type="button" href="#checkoutModal" id="checkoutModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">CHECKOUT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simplified solution. Just use `align-items: flex-end !important;` and `flex-direction`

by default `.modal-footer` is on `display:flex` in `bootstrap`. You just need `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: flex-end !important`;
and it should work just fine.

Run snippet below.

```css
.coinsTotalRow {
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

#checkoutModalBtn {
  background-color: var(--pri-color);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

#checkoutButtonStyle {
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #111111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3rem 5.6rem;
}

.modal-footer {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="coinsTotalRow">
    <p class="checkoutTotal">Total Coins: </p>
    <p id="checkoutcoinsTotal" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 10)">

      <p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" href="#checkoutModal" id="checkoutButtonStyle" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
  <button type="button" href="#checkoutModal" id="checkoutModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">CHECKOUT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, I did the following way for modal-footer class but it brings the whole footer top line towards the right with all of the elements.

Comment: @addy_sk  Try now. Please mention in the question that you have other elements in the footer for better clarity - I have updated the answer. Let me know.

Comment: hi, I am unable to move the custom style button right next to the text total coins. It goes something like this : Total coins =

Comment: @addy_sk hi, you want CHECKOUT button next to total coins OR below it. Please edit you question and add all relevant info there. So much confusion here :(

Comment: Sry about this. I would like the Checkout button under both the text and the custom style button and the total coins right beside the custom style button to display the coins.

Comment: @addy_sk Edit you question and add like a design or draw a picture of what you want. I do not understand what you mean sry.

Comment: Hi, I have used d-flex and flex row to help aid with the alignment of the 2 elements. appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @addy_sk Hi, i am glad to hear that. Thanks so much :)